# Интерфейс текстового поля администратор с django-tinymce

Tags: django, tinymce, django-admin

Всем привет! помогите подключить tinymce к интерфейсу администратора. В доках вроде сказано что он должен вроде появится автоматически после установки django-tinymce.
Поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь.
Вот файлы

---

**setting.py**

```
# coding=utf-8
Django settings for castaway project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'we5sw%xp^su2#+wmr**kxey_%bfy45cmdoga=0duid1s1z!c$j'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'castshop',
    'tinymce',
]


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'castaway.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'castaway.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'chzat',
        'USER': 'chzat',
        'PASSWORD': 'bgfqdwy0',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# LOGGING = {
#     'version': 1,
#     'disable_existing_loggers': False,
#     'handlers': {
#         # Log to a text file that can be rotated by logrotate
#         'logfile': {
#             'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
#             'filename': '/home/c/chzat/public_html/logfilename.log'
#         },
#     },
#     'loggers': {
#         # Might as well log any errors anywhere else in Django
#         'django': {
#             'handlers': ['logfile'],
#             'level': 'ERROR',
#             'propagate': False,
#         },
#     },
# }



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# SQL_STACKTRACE = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/js/tiny_mce/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
import castshop


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('castshop.urls')),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

]
```

А что дальше? Как подключить это у интерфейсу админа? Есть хардкорные методы путем правки change_form.html, ну мне кажется должно быть проще.

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В модели замените `models.TextField` на `tinymce.models.HTMLField`.